# Automarically uncheck rows in a p:datatable if row is not visible

Tags: primefaces

I'm facing a situation like this:

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtBasicView.cars}" rowSelectMode="checkbox">
    <p:column headerText="Id">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Year">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Brand">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Color">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

My goal is to auto uncheck all the rows that are not visible so basically the rows that are hidden or not in the current page of a paginated table.

Since I'm on Primefaces 6.2 I'd use "disabledSelection" attribute. 
I've tried various attempts with no luck like:

```
disabledSelection="#{car.rendered}"
```

or

```
disabledSelection="#{car.rowStyleClass = 'ui-helper-hidden'}"
```

But won't work.

Comment: Have you tried what suggested [here](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=33646)?

Comment: Aren't they unchecked by default? Don't see anything  that would check them